# Test APK does not resolve / load classes from main APK ~ Cannot load class 'android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2'

Tags: java, android, maven

I'm having trouble executing instrumentation tests using the android maven plugin.
I have followed the "libraryprojects" example to the last detail, however, 
there is one slight difference in my setup ~ i'm adding the android support jar as
an external dependency.

My setup looks as follows:

- APK lib project (greendroid to be specific)

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>r6</version>
  </dependency>        

  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```
- APK project

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>greendroid</groupId>
      <artifactId>GreenDroidFragment</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>   
      <type>apklib</type>                 
  </dependency>
  ```
- APK test project (and here's the problem .... )

  ```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r6</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>                   
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
          <artifactId>android</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
          <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.jayway.android.robotium</groupId>
          <artifactId>robotium-solo</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.**</groupId>
          <artifactId>**</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <type>apk</type>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.**</groupId>
          <artifactId>**</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <type>jar</type>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
  ```

The problem is that delvik is unable to find or link support jar upon running instrumentation tests.

My question is, **how do I tell delvik to resolve required files within the test APK against the main application APK** ? Theoretically, **setting the scope of the required dependency (android-support jar) to provided within the test APK should work, but it does not**.

Below are some scenarios that I experimented with:

- By packaging the android support jar as part of the APK test project, delvik complains that it's unable to resolve the compiled code. This is because the dex output of the main APK is different from the dex output of the test APK.

  ```
  W/dalvikvm(328): Class resolved by unexpected DEX:      
  Lcom/**/android/**/GenerateOtpFragment;(0x44edffb0):0x121de0 ref   
  [Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;] Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;(0x44edffb0)
  ```
- By not packaging the android support as part of the APK test project, delvik is unable to locate the compiled code. This happens when making the scope provided or excluding the dependency completely.

  ```
  W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(632): Cannot load class. Make sure it is in your apk.
  Class name: 'android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2'. 
  Message: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2
  ```

The only thing I can think of is to somehow manually tell the APK test project to resolve the android-support dependency from the main APK project using a delvik linking mechanism.

Any ideas would be much appreciated,
-Michael

Comment: i've pulled the main APK from the emulator device, and confirmed that the support jar is indeed packaged within the APK. After setting the support jar with "provided" scope within the test APK, delvik is still unable to load the required files ... somehow, and for some bizaar reason, the test APK is not referencing / loading all of the classes within the main APK

Comment: ok ... 2 weeks on, and i've had my first major insight. I had written a ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 test that referenced GDActivity as it's super class. Now, GDActivity is a subclass of FragmentActivity which in turn extends the Activity class that Instrumentation tests use to execute. I was able to confirm that the android support jar is indeed on the test APK's class-path.... which leads me to this conclusion: the instrumentation test framework does not support greendroid at this point in time ... so now my goal is to add a testing capability for fragment activities ...

Comment: more insight ... i was able to determine that some libraries play nicely, while others don't. E.g. the spring-android-rest-template and commons-lang libraries work well for the linrary-main_apk-test_apk setup. However, spring-core, spring-context-support and android-support v4 don't. The reason for this is that those artifacts were build using a "non-standard compiler". I'm using jdk6 on mac. It might be the installed JDK i'm using ... so i'm trying out a build on Fedora now to see if it makes any difference ...

Comment: execution on Fedora linux produced the same result ...

Comment: new insight ... i've determined that fragment support fails within a test APK for any application with API level < 13. Although the support v4 jar is supposed to work fine from API 4 onwards, it fails to be linked on any emulator with API < 13. My current synopsis is that a simple build and run works fine because the support libraries are loaded on demand, while in the case of a test APK, all the dex files are loaded one time and an attempt is made to link them all.

Comment: New insight here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/sotIalKQTUQ/r38h4OJ9cQ4J => Looks like running a single test "-e class ...." is not affected by this problem. whereas running all (or all from given package "-e package ...") has that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I suspect this might be an explanation:

[Instrumentation tests scanning apk...not an issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-test-kit-discuss/fXrT6is9Hw8)